# I have a blank window in node editor

Tags: rendering, blend-files

[image]

I got this blank window I did'nt see any node anyone how to show it ??

Comment: I suggest you use the 'new' button in the bottom bar

Comment: in Blender 2.8;
"use nodes" should be selected, on the bottom toolbar of the node editor

Answer (score 4):

That's perfectly normal. If you're trying to create a material, you should go to the Materials tab in the Properties panel and create a material if you don't have one already:

[image: Materials – New button]

Then click the "Use Nodes" button:

[image: Materials – Use Nodes button]

That should give you a simple diffuse shader in the node editor.

Comment: Or you can also press New button in the bottom of the Node editor which will do the same - create a new material and show its node tree for editing.